# Want to do task when multiple buttons are clicked simultaneously (Android Studio:java)

Tags: java, android-studio, button

I am creating a music app(flute) which play sounds when buttons are clicked. But i want to make a specific sound when multiple buttons are pressed simultaneously (example: playing c note when two buttons are pressed simultaneously).

There are seven buttons which makes seven different notes or sounds(c, d, e, f, g, a, b)

app should work as:

->play note c when button 2 and 3 are pressed simultaneously.

->play note d when button 2 is pressed.

->play note e when button 1 is pressed.

->play note f when button 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 are pressed simultaneously.

->play note g when button 2, 3,4,5 and 6 are pressed simultaneously.

->play note a when button 2, 3, 4 and 5 are pressed simultaneously.

->play note b when button 2, 3 and 4 are pressed simultaneously.

if anyone can help i would appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

```
button1down : a=1 play();
button1up : a=0 play();

button2down : b=1; play();
button2up : b=0; play();

.......
play(){
if(a&&b){
play_tone_ab();
}else
if(a){
play_tone_a();
}
}
```

the pseudocode will look like this. 
But you may face some other problems while playing music. Playing many sound files 
may lead to some other problems. Sometimes this is a hardware problem. So , you may need to make that part stable by testing the algorithm if right functions are called. Use system.log first to be sure . 
Still you may need a nice sound mixing library, which can remix the input sounds before output.

Comment: anyway , try openal audio library. sure you will need one.. openal was the way i solved a similar problem many years ago..